# Opening an email client on clicking a button

Tags: email, blackberry

I am designing an app in which i need open an email client on clicking a button. The email client should be opened with pre defined subject,'to' address and from address of the user. Is there a way to attain this??? Plz provide me the solution and code if possible...

Comment: Ehm .. What kind of programming language are we talking about? Web development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to open the existing BlackBerry messages application use the [Invoke](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2.1api/net/rim/blackberry/api/invoke/Invoke.html) class with the appropriate [MessageArguments](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2.1api/net/rim/blackberry/api/invoke/MessageArguments.html) e.g.

```
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MESSAGES, new MessageArguments(MessageArguments.ARG_NEW, <to address>, <subject>, <body>);
```

I don't know of a way to change the from address.